# how do i remove white spaces in between these images in bootstrap 3

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

Good day,

Am in the process of building a free wordpress theme for entrepreneurs but encountered this challenges:

[image: image describing what i want to achive]

1. I want to get rid of white spaces in between the post containers as show in the image above.
2. in the posts in between, the post dates are not displaying, i don't know why.

here are my code:

HTML/PHP

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="navbar">

<div>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" >
<?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
</div>

<div>
    <!--<h1 class="blog-title"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h1>-->
    <?php $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' ); ?>
<?php if($description) { ?><p class="blog-description"><?php echo $description ?></p><?php } ?></p>

    <?php wp_nav_menu (array( 
        'theme_location' => 'header-menu', 
        'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav pull-right' 
    ) ); ?>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.layerit {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding-top: 170px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
position: relative;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
text-align: center;
transition: background-color .9s ease;

}

.home-title {
 color: white;

 }

.home-author {
 color: white;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 90px;
}


 div.no-margin {

 }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `padding: 0; 
margin: 0;`
will do the trick.

Comment: 2. did you try `<span class="entry-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>`

Comment: Got all this fixed with padding: 0; margin: 0; thanks Dipu Raj and everyone but the latest problem am having is that whenever the post title is long, the box would overflow, how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

For vertical lines:
font-size: 0; on parent element

OR

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
li{
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

SHOULD BE

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
li{
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li><li></li>
</ul>
```

For horizontal lines:
vertical-align: top; for child elements

**EDIT**: Putting all `<li>` tags in a single line removes the whitespace in the markup, which is what's causing the spaces in the original question. Another more manageable way to fix it is to use html comments between the closing tag and the next opening one, like this:

```
<li>...</li><!--

--><li>...</li><!--

--><li>...</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @OloyedeJamiu no problem ;)